# truncating table on first monday of every month

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a backup table in which i want to store data for 1 month and every first monday of month that data should be truncated

```
Select * from table A into backup_Table 
case when its 1st monday of month 
Truncate Table Backup_table 
Else 
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

here i how you can calculate first Monday of current month

```
IF 
  (CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE())), 0) as date) = CAST(GETDATE() as date))
    Truncate Table Backup_table 
...
```